# Is there a shareable URL for randomstreetview.com that hides the location?

Tags: google-maps

I want to play an online icebreaker game with some colleagues about guessing the location from Google Street View. The idea is that as the quiz master I will find a random spot (where I know the location) and send them a URL. They should have no information about the location from the URL. Then can all look around and explore for 2 mins and then guess. Do you know of any existing setup for this? I think Geoguesser doesn't exactly work for this use case.

I found [randomstreetview.com](https://randomstreetview.com/) which is great and checks most of my boxes except one.

- [x] Randomly find location
- [x] Location info is available
- [x] Sharable url
- [ ] Hide location info

Is there a way to create a sharable URL where the location info, user controls to go to next image etc. are hidden?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. This question is asking for a software recommendation request and about using something you found. Software recommendations questions are off-topic here but might be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se]. Please [edit] the question to make it about a specific problem with using a specific web app to make it on-topic for this site.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to clarify if  you  are looking for support with Google Maps or [randomstreetview](https://randomstreetview.com/)  or looking for a site reccomendation that checks all your boxes.